# How to use new dataset on a pretrained neural network model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, dataset, machine-learning-model, finetuning

I have built a dataset that I would like to pass to a pretrained model in oder to perform some predictions. I am looking for some steps/processes to guide me in this. Should I fine tune?If so what exactly should I fine tune? Is there other ways?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I am new here too, but I would suggest reading https://blogs.rstudio.com/ai/posts/2017-12-14-image-classification-on-small-datasets/ if you are using Keras with R. It's about using pre-trained models and different types of fine-tuning.

Answer (score 0):

If there is high similarity in your dataset and pretained model dataset and

- If you have large amount of training samples, fine tune all layers of
  neural network model
- If you have small number of training samples,fine tune last few
  layers of model

If similarity between your dataset and pretrained model dataset is low and

- If you have large number of training samples, fine tune all
  layers or train the model from scratch.
- If you have small number of training samples, it is difficult to get good
  model performance. you can select a less complex network and train it
  with heavily augmented data or acquire more data.